# Script groovy tag not working properly in Play

Tags: java, groovy, playframework

Hey guys I am using the script tag.

%{..}%

When I do multiplication it seems to work.

```
up = wrapBenchmark * upperLimit;
```

But if I do this.

```
up = wrapBenchmark + upperLimit;
```

It seems to add the number as a string to the end.  Like a string concat.  What is the issue here?  I just want to add two numbers together.  It's treating everything as a string.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard String class (java) has overloaded operator + (string concat), and no overloaded operator * (multiply). So, interpreter casts variables to an integer, when cannot invoke multiply on string objects. And groovy is a dynamically typed language, so parameters sends like strings.

To solve your issue write this

```
up = wrapBenchmark.toInteger() + upperLimit.toInteger();
```

Comment: This works great.  What I don't get is the two integer's I'm adding work fine.  It was the double numbers that were a problem.